# Adt message converters - INTEGERS come as nulls

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-integration, spring-jdbc, oracle-aq

I am using following configuration for handling OracleAQ with adt payload...

```
<bean id="messageConverter"
   class="org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.support.converter.oracle.MappingAdtMessageConverter">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.data.jdbc.jms.support.oracle.StructDatumMapper"> 
      <constructor-arg index="0" value="MY_QUEUE"/>
      <constructor-arg index="1" value="MyMappedClass"/>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

the problem is that after dequeuing I am getting on java side null values for fields with INTEGERs and non null values for other fields.

```
MyMappedClass@649fe46f[
  id=<null>
  id2=<null>
  time=2013-02-22 14:57:11.0
  user=LUKAS
]
```

In queue table these values exists as not nulls.

What can be the reason. I expected bad mappings, but I don't see anything wrong there.
Those fields are mapped as Types.INTEGER.

Do you have maybe idea what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found that there are mistakes in generated mapping files. For Long field I had Integer setter. That was the reason why reflection api during conversion process regarded those fields as non writeable. So it was not library version or configuration problem.